# When I console.log class it returns null

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3, console.log

I make class userData to get a value of inputs of forms then make another class with LoginData with the same value but with another purpose. My problem when I `console.log` userData its work fine but when `console.log` loginData it returns `null`.

```
constructor(private alertCtrl: AlertController, public navCtrl: 
    NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public authService: 
    UserProvider, public loadingCtrl: LoadingController, private toastCtrl: 
    ToastController) { 

    console.log(this.loginData)
}

userData = {
    "name":  "",
    "email": "" ,
    "Type_Id" : "", 
    "Mobile" : "",
    "password": "",
};

loginData = {
    UserEmail: this.userData.name ,
    Password:  this.userData.email
}

signup(){
  this.showLoader();
  console.log(this.loginData)

  this.authService.postData(this.userData,'Regestier').then((result) => {
    var userinfo = this.responseData;

    console.log(this.responseData);
    localStorage.setItem('userinfo', this.responseData);

    this.login()
    /* if (this.responseData.Type_Id = "1"){
    this.navCtrl.push(CompanyProfilePage, {}, {animate: true, direction: 
    'forward'});
    }
    else
    {
      this.navCtrl.setRoot(DashboardPage, {}, {animate: true, direction: 
      'forward'});

    }*/

    this.loading.dismiss();
    this.presentPrompt()
 },

 (err) => {
   // Error log
    this.loading.dismiss();

  });

}
```

I want to use UserData to store signup form Data and LoginData to store login Data. The sign up working but login does not work. The problem is loginData returns `null`.

Comment: Is there any error in console? Did you tried to initialize `loginData` in `constructor`?

Comment: it's return undefined in console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your `userData` and `loginData` inside `constructor`.

```
export class MyComponent {

  userData; loginData;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

    this.userData = {
    "name":  "",
    "email": "" ,
    "Type_Id" : "", 
    "Mobile" : "",
    "password": "",
    };

    this.loginData = {
    UserEmail: this.userData.name ,
    Password:  this.userData.email
    };
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    console.log(this.loginData);
  }

}
```

[exmaple](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-nhx6iz?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make some changes to your declaration process.

Make use of the Angular lifecycle hook [`ngOnInit()`](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) to do your declarations:

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.loginData = {
       UserEmail: this.userData.name ,
       Password:  this.userData.email
    }
}
```

> The Constructor is a default method of the class that is executed when
>   the class is instantiated and ensures proper initialization of fields
>   in the class and its subclasses.
>
> ngOnInit is a life cycle hook called by Angular2 to indicate that
>   Angular is done creating the component.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Reactive forms which are very easy to use. First import it in your app.module.ts like this:

```
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

then add them to your imports array like this,

```
  imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule ],
```

this is how your component.ts can look like :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup,FormControl,FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

 @Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
 name = 'Angular';
 userData:FormGroup;
 constructor(fb:FormBuilder){
this.userData = fb.group({
  name : new FormControl(''),
  email : new FormControl(''),
  Type_Id : new FormControl(''),
  Mobile : new FormControl(''),
  Password : new FormControl(''),
 })
}

signup(){
console.log(this.userData.value.email);
console.log(this.userData.value.Password);
 }
}
```

Then your component.html file can look like this:

```
<form [formGroup]="userData" (ngSubmit)="signup()">
 <input type="text" formControlName="email">
 <input type="password" formControlName="Password">
 <button (click)="signup()">signup</button>
</form>
```

It should work now. Look more into reactive forms they are really awesome !